# Знаки после занятой, округление в Javascript.

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте! Как мне в ответе выводить 3 символа после запятой?

document.getElementById("result").value.toFixed(3) **- Не работает**

Var result = document.getElementById("result").value;
result.toFixed(3) **- Не работает**

---

**Мой код**

```
<input type="text" id="size" size="40">
        <input type="text" id="pices" size="40">
        <input type="button" value="Calculate" onClick="calcsum()">
        <input type="text" id="result" size="27">

<script>
function calcsum() {
        var si = document.getElementById("size").value;
        var pi = document.getElementById("pices").value;
        document.getElementById("result").value = Number(si) * Number(pi);

    }
    </script>
```

Comment: Используйте методы `getAttribute()` для получения и `setAttribute()` для установки атрибутов.

Answer (score 1):

[toFixed()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tofixed.asp) - это метод объекта Number. Возможно вы в value получали String, поэтому и не работало. Вот так все работает http://jsfiddle.net/wQAQS/1/

Кстати,

```
typeof parseFloat("3.456456").toFixed(2) == 'string'; // вот такие дела
```

По поводу всяких преобразований и сравнений нарыл очень занимательный бложек http://wtfjs.com/